# C++ alternative to singleton design when a function-only class needs to be initialize at least once?

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, design-patterns, singleton

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class MathClass {
private:
    size_t current_capacity;
    double* logfact;
    bool inited = false;
    
    MathClass() {
        current_capacity = 0;
        logfact = new double[1];
        logfact[0] = 0;
    }
    
    void calculateLogFact(int n) {
        if (current_capacity >= n) return;
        double* newLogfact = new double[n+1];
        for (int i=0; i<=current_capacity; i++) newLogfact[i] = logfact[i];
        for (int i=current_capacity+1; i<=n; i++) newLogfact[i] = newLogfact[i-1] + log(double(i));        
        delete[] logfact;
        logfact = newLogfact;
    }
    
    double factorial(int n) {
        cout << "n = " << n << "\n";
        calculateLogFact(n);
        for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) cout << int64_t(round(exp(logfact[i]))) << " ";
        cout << "\n";
        return exp(logfact[n]);
    }
    
public:

    static double factorial2n(int n) {
        static MathClass singleton;
        return singleton.factorial(2*n);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
    cout << MathClass::factorial2n(10) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

My library need to use an expensive function that needs to be initialized once before use (to pre-calculate some expensive values so that we don't have to calculate them every time). Currently, I use the singleton method above for this.

However, there are 2 problems:

1. Multi-threading: this will cause race conditions if 2 different threads call this function.
2. People don't like singleton
3. Other problems that I'm not aware of

What other design can I use to solve this problem? Pre-computing values is a must since this function needs to be fast.

Comment: I would encourage you to use the std::vector class for the `logfact` array instead of manually allocating a longer array each time. std::vector can adjust its size automatically if you add elements and does not copy all elements each time you extend it. You should add a destuctor to free the array if you insist on manually allocating the array.

Comment: Thanks, I just typed that quickly as an example. But the main question still remains

Comment: Your static object `singleton` is local to `factorial2n()` so cannot be accessed outside it.   It will be initialised exactly once when `factorial2n()` is called the first time, and that will (from C++11) be thread safe.

Comment: @Peter is that a new feature of C++11? What if the first run takes 5 minutes to initialize (such as init from DB), and at the start at the program I make 2 threads and both of them call factorial2n() ?

Comment: @Peter the static object `singleton` has non-read-only member variables that may be changed if `factorial2n()` is called. This is **not** thread safe.

Comment: @Peter: The initialization of the singleton is indeed thread safe, but the class itself is not thread safe...

Comment: Singleton is not exposed, it is just a static cache. Your multithreading issue is not directly related to singleton.

Comment: Expose the fact that you cache results and don't try abstracting it away. There's no mental model that explains why a pure function should cause data races. In other words, let the user create their own `MathClass` and manage it.

Comment: If you have two threads that are calling `factorial2n()` then the construction of the object is safe.  But, since both threads will then (potentially) concurrently change the object, those threads need to synchronise.    There is a rule of thumb that applies here:   no object can protect itself against two threads that concurrently modify it, so the two threads need to synchronise.

Comment: @PasserBy so do you think the solution is just use a regular class instead of a singleton class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with comments: Why hide the fact that `MathClass` caches results from the user? I, as a potential user, see no real benefit, rather potential confusion. If I want to reuse previously cached results stored in an instance I can do that. You need not wrap the whole class in a singleton for me to enable that. Also there is no need to manually manage a dynamic array when you can use `std::vector`.

In short: The alternative to using a singleton is to not use a singleton.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class MathClass {
private:
    size_t current_capacity;
    std::vector<double> logfact;
    bool inited = false;
    
    void calculateLogFact(int n) {
        if (logfact.size() >= n) return;
        auto old_size= logfact.size();
        logfact.resize(n);
        for (int i=old_size; i<n; i++) logfact.push_back(logfact.back() + log(double(i)));        
    }
    
    double factorial(int n) {
        cout << "n = " << n << "\n";
        calculateLogFact(n);
        for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) cout << int64_t(round(exp(logfact[i]))) << " ";
        cout << "\n";
        return exp(logfact[n]);
    }
    
public:
    MathClass() {
        logfact.push_back(0);
    }
    double factorial2n(int n) {
       return factorial(2*n);
    }
};

void foo(MathClass& mc) { // some function using previously calculated results
    std::cout << mc.factorial2n(2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
    MathClass mc;
    cout << mc.factorial2n(10) << "\n";
    foo(mc);
}
```

I am not sure if the maths is correct, I didn't bother to check. Also `inited` and most of the includes seem to be unused.

Concerning "Multi-threading: this will cause race conditions if 2 different threads call this function." I would also not bother too much to bake the thread-safety into the type itself. When I want to use it single-threaded I do not need thread-safety, and I don't want to pay for it. When I want to use it multi-threaded, I can do that by using my own `std::mutex` to protect access to the `mc` instance.

PS: Frankly, I think the whole issue is caused by a misconception. Your `MathClass` is not a "function only" class. It is a class with state and member functions, just like any other class too. The "misconception" is to hide the state from the user and pretend that there is no state when in fact there is state. When using this class I would want to be in conctrol what results I can query because they are already cached and which results need to be computed first. In other words, I would provide more access to the class state, rather than less.